# Automatic generation of views for multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I'm looking for a way to automatically create a 1:1 view per table for a bunch of tables. Since there are plenty of tables for which I need a view, it would be time-consuming to create them manually. All table names are listed within a table and could be iterated.

The perfect scenario would be a query creating the create view queries for each table given at once.

Comment: Its pretty straight forward to write a script that will query the system tables and build the script to create the view. Give it a go and let us know when you get stuck.

Comment: Have you considered a [DDL trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/ddl-triggers?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a snippet to get you started.

```
select concat(quotename(schema_name(t.schema_id)), '.', quotename(t.name)) name , string_agg(quotename(c.name), ', ') columns
from sys.tables t
join sys.columns c
  on t.object_id = c.object_id
where t.is_ms_shipped = 0
group by t.object_id, t.schema_id, t.name
```